# Имя в конце объявления. Что это за синтаксическая конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис

Например: "По всем вопросам обращаться по телефону 89854214632, Михаил." Как трактовать имя подавшего объявление с точки зрения синтаксиса?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, Вы вступили на поле, где играют без правил. Корректно было бы так:   обращаться к Михаилу по телефону 89854214632.

Мне кажется, Михаил - не тот, кто подал объявление, а тот, кто отвечает на звонки.

Comment: Лучше так: По всем вопросам обращаться по телефону 89854214632. Писал Михаил.

Comment: @Jasmin  Тут важно, что Михаил отвечает на звонки. А кто писал, не имеет значения. Скорее всего, писал кто-то другой из отдела рекламы.

Comment: @Jasmin. А если Михаил подал объявление, то можно просто написать имя после точки, как подпись в конце письма. Тогда вопрос остается:  что это за синтаксическая конструкция?

Comment: Есть еще вариант: к сему руку приложил  Михаил. В самом  широком  смысле, то есть стал соучастником. Тогда и синтаксис очень понятный: БСП, второе предложение неполное. Вот здесь про "руку приложил" интересно написано: http://frazbook.ru/2011/01/28/prilozhit-ruku/

Answer (score 1):

Данное предложение входит в состав **упрощенной**   записи делового стиля.

Обычно структура  официальных деловых писем **регламентируется специальными стандартами**. Например: https://www.sekretariat.ru/oformlenie-pisem

Подпись –  заключительный **структурный элемент** делового письма, текст которого заканчивается точкой.

В приведенном примере **точку заменили запятой**.

В любом случае это **условное оформление делового текста** и к теме синтаксического разбора предложений  отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 0):

По функциональному назначению это **перечисление реквизитов адреса** (по которому предложено обращаться) в форме "*номер телефона, контактное лицо*". Соответствует ли это каким-либо формальным требованиям (они не всегда определяются языковыми нормативами, например, требования к написанию почтового адреса менялись постановлениями правительства) - вопрос отдельный, но любой носитель языка поймёт всё правильно.

Comment: Смысл подписи более или менее ясен, автора синтаксис интересует.  Надо сделать разбор предложения по всем правилам.

Comment: Так или иначе, "Михаил" в таком предложении - _не_ подпись и _не_ автор (написать мог любой участник общего дела или организации - это не важно, даже телефон не обязательно личный), а элемент другой, более общей конструкции. Важно то, _как_ обратиться по этому телефону.

Comment: Я не сразу обратил внимание на то, как сформулирован вопрос: "Как трактовать **имя подавшего объявление** с точки зрения синтаксиса?". Если следовать за автором вопроса, то   Михаил — подпись.